# The timestamp of messages at client use local time, how can I make it use server time

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

(10:33:59) ooo: hello
(10:34:19) qq: hello,how are you!

The timestamp of messages at client use local time, I want to use server time，how could I

do？ I use pidgin.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an ejabberd module that inserts an extra XML tag with a timestamp in the stanza.

https://github.com/johanvorster/ejabberd_add_timestamp

I'm not familiar with Pidgin, but I'd suspect you should be able to read custom attributes.
If not, you might need to parse the raw stanza and extract the tag that way.